# C# convert byte[] to string with a charset

Tags: c#, string, arrays

In C# How can we convert byte[] to string with a charset.eg utf8,SHIFT_JIS,and more
.I know Encoding.UTF8

```
byte[] inputBytes =SupportClass.ToByteArray(readBytes);
StringBuilder result;
result.Append(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length));//get unreadable code.
```

my question is how can I get the result from inputBytes with a special charset,like java

```
StringBuffer result.append(new String(buffer, "SJIS"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis");
result.Append(enc.GetString(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length));
```

See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332097(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Good answer,but when I use System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030"),it seems not fire.what's wrong,indeed encoding name  "gb2312" is wantted,but in your linked page I can't find this encoding name; this puzzled me.

Comment: Both GB18030 and GB2312 can used with GetEncoding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx) - please clarify what problem you are facing (potentially in a new question).

Comment: In wp7,gb2312 is not supportted!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Encoding.UTF8`, use [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c.aspx).

E.g.

```
private static readonly Encoding SHIFT_JIS = Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS");

SHIFT_JIS.GetString(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length)
```